# How to specify different user library path for different actions in an oozie workflow

Tags: java, apache-spark, oozie, hue, oozie-workflow

How to specify different user library path for different actions in an oozie workflow

I have a spark action and a java action

```
<workflow-app name="batch-publisher" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to="spark-a5b5"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="spark-a5b5">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.libpath</name>
                    <value>${nameNode}/user/hdfs/sps-batch-bi/Jars/</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.use.system.libpath</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <master>yarn</master>
            <mode>client</mode>
            <name>MySpark2</name>
              <class>com.sps.analytics.batch.bi.BatchApp</class>
            <jar>${nameNode}/user/hdfs/sps-batch-bi/Jars/sps-analytics-batch-bi-assembly-0.1.jar</jar>
              <spark-opts>--driver-memory 4G --executor-memory 4G --num-executors 2</spark-opts>
              <arg>/user/hdfs/sps-batch-bi/config.yaml</arg>
              <arg>/user/hdfs/sps-batch-bi/Query_sps_txn_Detail.xlsx</arg>
              <arg>spark</arg>
        </spark>
        <ok to="java-8283"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <action name="java-8283">
        <java>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.map.env</name>
                    <value>LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/tableau/lib64/tableausdk/</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.user.classpath.first</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <main-class>com.sps.analytics.bi.publisher.PublisherApp</main-class>
            <arg>sps-data-bi-dev</arg>
            <arg>default</arg>
            <arg>default</arg>
            <file>/user/sps/bi-publisher/config/application.properties#application.properties</file>
        </java>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

How can I specify different library paths for two actions. I have conflicitng jars in these two assembly jars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the action s sub-workflow helps resolves the jar incosistencies

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
     <action name="java-8283">
        ...
        <java>
            <file>hdfs://xx/xx/xx.jar</file>
            <file>hdfs://xx/xx/xx.jar</file>
        </java>
        <ok to="End"/>
        ...
     </action>
```